# Please reopen "How to search catalogues and evade interlibrary loan fees, for libraries outside the London Libraries Consortium?"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Can https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/79991/47623 please be reopened? Reasons:

1. My grandparents are travelling to London and ask this as travellers.
2. This question  affects travellers. The [City of Westminster's library](https://www.westminster.gov.uk/how-do-I-join-a-library) discusses guests and visitors:

> > Short stay membership
>
> If you are living in short-term accommodation, you can apply for
>   either short stay membership or a visitor's subscription membership.
>
> Guest member
>
> If you are visiting Westminster and unable to provide proof of a UK
>   address, you can join as a guest member. You can use our computers and
>   online resources free of charge for one month but you will be unable
>   to borrow books. You will need to provide proof of identity eg a
>   passport, identity card, etc.

Answer (score 8):

I'll let somebody else (OP?) put the case for re-opening this question but for the sake of something to vote on to indicate pros and cons I say **not suitable to re-open**.

I see negligible 'Travel' in *How to search catalogues and evade interlibrary loan fees*.